# Does db_datawriter have a read permission on a database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm learning more about Microsoft SQL Server and I get confused about what each database-level role does.  I read an article which defines
db_datawriter as follows:

> Members of the db_datawriter fixed database role can add, delete, or change data in all user tables.

I was wondering does db_datawriter have a read permission too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will grant write abilities such as `insert`, `update`, and `delete`.

> Members of the db_datawriter fixed database role can
> add, delete, or change data in all user tables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15